# MicrosoftKeyboardHelper and MicrosoftMouseHelper

Tags: macos, mac

I have neither a Microsoft Mouse nor a Microsoft Keyboard, nor any Microsoft software installed on my Mac.  Why then do I have **MicrosoftKeyboardHelper** and **MicrosoftMouseHelper** running in my process list?  Their parent process is launchd.

Comment: Hah! A google search for "MicrosoftKeyboardHelper" brings this up as the second result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the computer have had a Microsoft keyboard or mouse connected at any time in the past?

If so the drivers may have been installed when the Microsoft KB & M were being used, and not uninstalled when the KB & M were removed.

You would probably be safe to uninstall the software/drivers if it is causing a problem.

Comment: I think I had plugged a Microsoft keyboard into my Mac years ago.  Now, I need to figure out where to uninstall them.

Comment: To be honest, im not terribly familiar with Macs, and thus do not completely understand how it handles drivers. As joshhunt mentioned, its worth a look in the Applications folder or Login Items folder for anything with a name similar to "MicrosoftKeyboardHelper". Also you could try AppDelete, its free and helps to remove any remanents of deleted files. AppDelete can be found here: http://reggie.ashworth.googlepages.com/appdelete

Answer (score 2):

Inside your Applications folder, open the "Utilities" folder. There should be an "Intellipoint Uninstaller.app" there. Run that and it should remove the Helper Apps/processes. (Note that it will ask you to reboot at the end of the process.)

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You must have installed them at some point. You can either dig around for the files that launch them yourself, or you can run this and see if it catches them for you:

http://www.khiltd.com/Downloads/ConsultantsCanary.tar.gz

It won't actually remove anything, just point it out.

Answer (score 0):

What an oddity. Do you have a 'Microsoft Keyboard.app' in Applications? It appears as if that is the source of these daemons. If that is present, try removing it. These also may be present in **System Preferences** > **Users** > [**Your User**] > **Login Items**

AFAICT, this program is a part of the IntelliType tools for OS X to enable extra functionality on certain keyboards. If you are certain that you have never used a Microsoft keyboard, it could be possible that you have used another keyboard with similar hardware and they have used used the same program to enable said functionality. Another possibility is that these have installed themselves as a part of other Microsoft software.